# Adding code like how you can do with a new ClassName(){}?

Tags: java, iterator, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Sorry if the title is worded badly, I struggled to come up with words to explain this in a simple title. Yeah, this is a Minecraft thing, but due to this being an old version and the code already working individually, and it being mostly a Java thing I think it's fit to say this here.
So, I want to hook into all instances of BlockFence, and replace them with my own class that can connect to other fences. This part is easy enough. However, the class must be an instance of the class I'm replacing, and almost every mod makes a child class for the type of block they're adding. So I decided to iterate through all fences and try to add in my code:

```
            Iterator<Block> iterator = Block.blockRegistry.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Block block = iterator.next();
            if(block instanceof BlockFence) {
                String name = Block.blockRegistry.getNameForObject(block);
                GameRegistry.addSubstitutionAlias(name, GameRegistry.Type.BLOCK, block);
                GameRegistry.addSubstitutionAlias(name, GameRegistry.Type.ITEM, new ItemBlock(block));
            }
        }
```

If you don't play Minecraft, basically you can replace blocks and items in the game's registry with your own version, and what I'm trying to do it replace it with an identical instance of its class. I'm stuck here though.
For vanilla fences, this isn't a problem since I already have access to the class. Here's an example of working Nether Brick Fence replacement code:

```
            Block block = new BlockFence("nether_brick", Material.rock) {
            public boolean canConnectFenceTo(IBlockAccess p_149826_1_, int p_149826_2_, int p_149826_3_, int p_149826_4_)
            {
                Block block = p_149826_1_.getBlock(p_149826_2_, p_149826_3_, p_149826_4_);
                return !(block instanceof BlockFence) && !(block instanceof BlockFenceGate) ? (block.getMaterial().isOpaque() && block.renderAsNormalBlock() ? block.getMaterial() != Material.gourd : false) : block.getMaterial() == blockMaterial;
            }
        };
        block.setHardness(2.0F).setResistance(10.0F).setStepSound(Block.soundTypePiston).setBlockName("netherFence");
        GameRegistry.addSubstitutionAlias("minecraft:nether_brick_fence", GameRegistry.Type.BLOCK, block);
        GameRegistry.addSubstitutionAlias("minecraft:nether_brick_fence", GameRegistry.Type.ITEM, new ItemBlock(block));
```

So how can I do the new ClassName() {some code} thing, but with a dynamic class variable? Basically, imagine me doing the above, but in the first block instead using the iterated code variable.

Comment: The `new ClassName() { ... }` syntax creates an instance of an _anonymous class_. It sounds like you're asking how to generate a class at runtime?

Comment: Yeah, basically. How can I generate a class based on the one I've iterated to and add a method to it, like I did with BlockFence earlier?

Comment: There's [a decent amount of existing information](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+generate+class+at+runtime) about generating classes at runtime. But I can't promise this is the correct approach for your specific situation. I also have no idea about what mechanisms Minecraft's and Forge's APIs already provide in terms of generating classes.